# values are getting added to base class instead of Derived Class object

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Im trying Method overriding,  I didnt get where the mistake I did.
The below is the code i have tried.
'#pragma once
#include 
using namespace std;

```
            class Queue {
                int size;
                int* queue;
            
            public:
                Queue() {
                    size = 0;
                    queue = new int[100];
                }
                void add(int data) {
                    queue[size] = data;
                    size++;
                }
                void print() {
                    if (size == 0) {
                        cout << "Queue is empty" << endl;
                        return;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        cout << queue[i] << " <- ";
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }
            };
            
            class Queue2 : public Queue
            {
                int size;
                int* queue;
            public:
                Queue2() {
                    size = 0;
                    queue = new int[100];
                }
                void print() {
                    if (size == 0)
                    {
                        cout << "Queue is empty" << endl;
                        return;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        cout << queue[i] << endl;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            };
            
            int main() {
                Queue q1;
                q1.add(42); q1.add(2); q1.add(8);  q1.add(1);
                q1.print();
            
                Queue2 q2;
                q2.add(3); q2.add(66); q2.add(128);  q2.add(5); q2.add(111); q2.add(77890);
                q2.print();
            
                return 0;
            }'
```

My Out Put :

```
42 <- 2 <- 8 <- 1 <-
Queue is empty
```

Expected Out Put:

```
42 <- 2 <- 8 <- 1 <-
3
66
128
5
111
77890
```

Answer (score 1):

Members are inherited (whether private or not). Its not clear why you repeat members in the derived class and then expect that the base class methods are using them.

```
class Queue {
            int size;
            int* queue;
```

The `Queue`s methods are using those members. On the other hand,

```
class Queue2 : public Queue {
            int size;
            int* queue;
```

Those members in the derived class shadow the members from the base. Hence, in `main` when you use `Queue2` you are populating the `queue` member in the base `Queue::queue` by calling `Queue::add`, but then try to print contents of `Queue2::queue` via calling `Queue::print`.

You can fix it by declaring the members in the base as `protected` and remove them in the derived:

```
class Queue {
    protected:
            int size;
            int* queue;
    ....



class Queue2 : public Queue {
         // int size;    // remove them
         // int* queue;  // Queue2 already has those members inherited from its base
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/xs3jqjoaj)

Last but not least, there is no overriding in your code. For `Queue2::print` to override `Queue::print` the method would need to be `virtual` in the base class. You should then declare the method as `override` in the derived class to get a compiler error when there is no overriding:

```
struct Queue {
    virtual void print() {}
};
            
struct Queue2 : Queue {
    void print() override {}
};
```

---

To illustrate that a derived object has both members, the one from the base class and the one from the derived class, even though the two member have the same name, consider following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base {
    int value = 42;
    void print(){
        std::cout << value << "\n";   // refers to base::value
                                      // inheritance will not change that
    }
};

struct derived : base {
    int value = 12;
    void set_value(int v){
        value = v;          // refers to derived::value
        base::value = 12;   // fully qualifying the name allows to 
                            // refer to base::value
    }
};
            
int main() {
    derived d;                
    d.set_value(10000);
    std::cout << d.value << "\n"; // refers to derived::value
    std::cout << d.base::value << "\n"; // refers to base::value
}
```

Output is:

```
10000
12
```

When you make the members private, they are still present in the derived class, but [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup)  will stop once it finds `derived::value`, hence in the derived class `value` refers to `derived::value`.

Comment: Thanks,  After converting to protected in Class Queue & removing the variables in Class Queue2 it worked fine.

Comment: having one doubt,  i didnt get why using private in base & derived class is causing the issue.
can u give some explanation why the issue will occur with using private

class Queue {
    private:
            int size;
            int* queue;
 public:
   void print(){}
    ....
 }
 class Queue2 : public Queue {
 private:
         int size;    
         int* queue;
 public:
   void print(){}
 }

Comment: @CharanSiddartha I thought I already explained that. See edit